# get the taxonomies terms associated with users

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy, users, user-meta

I’m building a search form with `meta_query` to get users based on `meta_key` and `meta_value`.

Some `meta_key` are taxonomies.

It works very well but in my select, i have all terms and some terms are not used by users but by post_type or buddypress group.

I get all terms this way :

```
$genres = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'genre',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
```

But i want to get only the terms associated with users (for example the terms are in `usermeta` with `meta_key = user_type_film`

For post type, it’s easy but i can find a solution for users.

Is there a WordPress method to do that ? I’ve searched in the codex and i don’t see what I'm looking for . Do i need to build my custom sql query ?